# Get a valid schema of large (1 GB) xml files

Tags: sql, xml, xsd, sqlbulkcopy, sqlxml

I need to bulk load huge xml files to SQL Server 2005. I decided to use SQLXMLBULKLOAD in my C# app, but I need to get valid xsd-schemas of those xml files to load them. Which is best way to generate xsd file?
I tried MS VS xsd.exe, but it tries to load the file into memory, which causes OutOfMemory exception.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip the file down to create a smaller one that is representative of the whole, then generate an XSD from that. You can then tailor the result if necessary.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I think about that. Could you tell me which tool will be good for me to generate the XSD?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2008 can definitely generate a schema for a given XML document. I don't know about 2005 though.

Comment: I would prefer to integrate a schema generation into my C# program. The idea of using just a part of XML file for schema generating is great, but there is another problem - how to generate a **valid** XML schema for SQLXMLBulkLoad?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few tools to generate schemas from instances, but I don't know how many of them are able to operate in pure streaming mode. One tool which will work regardless of the file size is the DTDGenerator that was originally part of Saxon; you can find it here:

http://saxon.sourceforge.net/dtdgen.html

It produces a DTD rather than a schema, but there are plenty of tools available to convert a DTD to a schema.

Comment: It requires Java machine, so I'm not able to use this tool with my app. Thank you anyway!

Comment: It's easy enough to convert it to a .NET application using IKVMC if that's a constraint.